# Zabbix cyrillic charsets wrong

Tags: zabbix

I have troubles with charsets in zabbix.
I use zabbix 3.4v and i tried change DB charsets to UTF8, cp1251, latin1, nothing didn't help me.
My zabbix agent send to server values with Cyrillic characters, but zabbix server receive all of them with question symbols. What i should to do?
How to fix problem?

Comment: Does `zabbix_get -s <host> -k <key>` give the correct output?

Comment: @astafev.evgeny yes of course, on server side, i run powershell command which give me some values with cyrillic symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you did not properly set database as utf8, which is he only supported encoding. You haven't specified the DB engine, though. In case of MySQL, it is not enough to change encoding of tables, the existing data must be converted, too.

The following should set the defaults and convert all the tables (assuming MySQL authentication is properly configured). Please note that this could take a very long time on a large database.

Make sure to have database backup before doing this.

```
mysql -N zabbix -e 'ALTER DATABASE zabbix DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;'
for table in $(echo "show tables;" | mysql -N zabbix); do echo "ALTER TABLE $table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;" | mysql -N zabbix; done
```

Comment: Can are you tell me please how and where i should do it?

Comment: You still haven't mentioned which DB you use - added example commands for MySQL.